# Como separar uma string por datas?

Tags: python, regex, split

Fiz a captura de uma string através de um regex. A string é:

```
"AGO/2021 Band. Verm. P2 - SET/2021 Band. Esc. Hídrica".
```

O regex utilizado foi:

```
r"[A-Z]{3}\/[0-9 ]{4} Band[.]* [a-zA-Z]+[.]* \w+ \- [A-Z]{3}\/[0-9 ]{4} Band[.]* [a-zA-Z]+[.]* [a-zA-Z-\W]+".
```

Gostaria de separar essa string pelas duas datas nela composta, ou seja:

```
str1 = AGO/2021 Band. Verm. P2
str2 = SET/2021 Band. Esc. Hídrica
```

Tentei fazer separação também por regex utilizando `split()`, porém sem muito sucesso. Alguma sugestão?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pra separar usando regex tem que usar a [função `split` do módulo `re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split). Além disso, o ideal é colocar o código como texto. Colocá-lo como imagem não é o ideal, entenda os motivos [lendo o **FAQ**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/112052). Então clique em [edit] e faça isso, mas coloque também um [mcve], pois não sabemos o que esse `parse_match_template` faz, então nem temos como testar o seu código...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Considerando a string final :

```
 "AGO/2021 Band. Verm. P2 - SET/2021 Band. Esc. Hidrica"
```

É possível separar essa string utilizando o `split()` da seguinte forma :

```
var= "AGO/2021 Band. Verm. P2 - SET/2021 Band. Esc. Hidrica"
var=var.split('-')
print (var[0],var[1])
```